# how to get rid of repetitive&common text in R

Tags: r, textedit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlZFC.jpg)

I want to get rid of "-n" at the end of every word in my data frame.
Is there any way to do this in R?

Comment: You say every word in your data frame.  Does your data frame consist of just words or are they multi-word strings line "test-n string-n"?

Comment: try look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871249/can-i-use-gsub-on-each-element-of-a-data-frame)

Comment: I tried to add image but it failed.. there is a column and data is like "end-n, firing-n, game-n"

Comment: Try `dput(head(df$TextColumn, 20))`  and paste the results into your question.

Comment: I'm sorry but what does "df" mean..?

Comment: `sub('-.*', '', 'some-n')`

Answer (score 3):

```
gsub('-n$','', 'my_word-n')
[1] "my_word"

#to make this work for the whole data frame you can do 

my_new_df <- sapply(my_old_df, function(x) gsub('-n$','', x))
```

Comment: If it has to be at the end, you need `'-n$'`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the unwanted string from the end of *every* word, try

```
gsub('-n\\b','', df$TextColumn)
```

Comment: If you want to save the result , you need something like `df$TextColumn = gsub('-n\\b','', df$TextColumn)`