# Regex search for specific pattern, if found, replace with something else

Tags: r, regex

I am currently trying to figure out how to use regex in order to clean up my textual data in R. I wonder where I could find an easy tutorial for it? I have been looking a bit online, but when I try something out on regex101 I hardly ever find matches. And if I do, within R, nothing changes. Consider this example

```
Before <- "ACEMOGLU, D., ROBINSON, J., (2012) WHY NATIONS FAIL, (3)"
After <- "ACEMOGLU, D., ROBINSON, J., 2012, WHY NATIONS FAIL, (3)"


> Aftergsub <- gsub("\\([\\d][\\d][\\d][\\d]\\)", "new", "ACEMOGLU, D., ROBINSON, J., (2012) WHY NATIONS FAIL, (3)")
> print(Aftergsub)
[1] "ACEMOGLU, D., ROBINSON, J., (2012) WHY NATIONS FAIL, (3)"
>
```

Of course the "new" should be an expression that would make Before look like After. But I don't even get to change Before into anything else, based on my pattern.

In  other words, how do I only change a ")" to a "," if it has been preceded by 4 digits? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern does not work because TRE regex flavor does not support shorthand character classes inside bracket expressions. You should either use `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]`, but not `[\\d]` (that actually [matches a `\` or a letter `d`](https://ideone.com/YJC5p3)).

You may use

```
Before <- "ACEMOGLU, D., ROBINSON, J., (2012) WHY NATIONS FAIL, (3)"
gsub("\\((\\d{4})\\)", "\\1,", Before)
## => [1] "ACEMOGLU, D., ROBINSON, J., 2012, WHY NATIONS FAIL, (3)"
```

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/7zQtwe)

**NOTE** that I am using `\\d`  **without** square brackets (=bracket expression) around it. TRE regex engine treats `"\\d{4}"` as a four digit matching pattern. It is equal to `[0-9]{4}` or `[[:digit:]]{4}`.

**Details**

- `\\(` - a literal  `(`
- `(\\d{4})` - Group 1: any four digits
- `\\)` - a literal `)`
- `\\1` - the backreference to Group 1 value

Comment: you could also pass the variable instead of value in the `gsub`,
`gsub("\\((\\d{4})\\)", "\\1,", Before)`

Comment: Yeah, that is what OP will do in the end. I will include the code here.

Comment: I need to run such a gsub over many different entries, so if Sagar says I can pass the variable indead of the value, would that work also on other entries? If so, how would it look like, i.e. gsub("\\((\\d{4})\\)", "\\1,", "my.dataframe")?

Comment: @SteffiWinkler Usually, it looks like `df$col1 <- gsub("\\((\\d{4})\\)", "\\1,", df$col1)` but you may run it on the whole data frame, too (but with a bit different code, see [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871249/can-i-use-gsub-on-each-element-of-a-data-frame)).

Comment: I think this would do then?  Split.CR[] <- lapply(Split.CR, gsub, pattern='\\((\\d{4})\\)', replacement='\\1, Split.CR')

Comment: If you need to process a column, use `gsub` directly as I have shown. Else, adjust as you see fit.

Comment: It seems to work, but I don't completely get the explanation that I should use [[:digit:]] or [0-9], whereas you still use a "d".

Comment: @SteffiWinkler: I used `"\\d"`, **not** `"[\\d]"`. That is  a huge difference for a TRE regex engine. I added a bit of an explanation under the snippet.